# appending data on the run throw null exception while data is already showing in debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

the `foreach` in the `cshtml` file throws null exception when appending data to the table data element

I tried debugging

```cs
@foreach (onlineStore.Areas.Admin.Models.orderModel i in ViewBag.data)
{
       <tr>
           <td>@i.uName</td>
           <td>@i.oDate</td>
           <td>@i.tCost</td>  //throws exception here 
           <td>
           <a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Admin" asp-area="Admin" asp-route-userid="@ViewBag.i.oID" class="btn btn-primary">Details</a>
           </td>
       </tr>
}
```

[here is an image of the data at he debugging](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i-vmUU1g_hXRJaIxvSuPM4OspOmfjFFg)

The exception is:

> "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot
>   perform runtime binding on a null reference'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need check `ViewBag.data != null` before using.

And may be use wrong variable `@ViewBag.i.oID` change to `i.oID`

```
@if (ViewBag.data != null)
{
     foreach (onlineStore.Areas.Admin.Models.orderModel i in ViewBag.data)
     {
         <tr>
             <td>@i.uName</td>
             <td>@i.oDate</td>
             <td>@i.tCost</td>  //throws exception here
             <td>
                 <a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Admin" asp-area="Admin" asp-route-userid="@i.oID" class="btn btn-primary">Details</a>
             </td>
         </tr>
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot maybe i was coding for too long that i started loosing focus your reply did fix my problem :D